# How to check for null fields in CSV file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv-simple

My CSV file will look like this (pipe separated):

```
apple|banana|pear||grapefruit
lemon|lime|damson|jackfruit
|tangerine|nectarine|plum
apricot|orange|pineapple|coconut|
```

(Assume that any sort of whitespace or special characters may be in the individual fields.)

I have to check if any value in any column is null, including the first and last columns.

Expected output:

```
apple|banana|pear||grapefruit
|tangerine|nectarine|plum
apricot|orange|pineapple|coconut|
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try `grep '||'`

Comment: grep '||' wont catch the line starts with pipe symbol. ( means.. first field is empty )

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322265/i-have-to-check-whether-each-column-in-csv-file-are-null-or-not-using-shell-scri#comment566520_322265), the easy and obvious answer would be `grep '||'`, but this would fail to catch cases where the first or last column is null.

So the correct answer (still using `grep`) is:

```
grep '^|\|||\||$' file.txt
```

The `|` character is not special to Grep unless escaped with a backslash, or unless the `-E` option is specified.  Still, this is a little unclear, so let's see what it would look like if the delimiter in the file were a *comma*:

```
grep '^,\|,,\|,$' file.txt
```

---

If you want to omit lines where only the *last* field is null, but print lines where any other field is null, just omit the last case:

```
grep '^|\|||' file.txt
```

---

Actually, it's easier to see what's going on if you put the individual cases in separate arguments, like so:

```
grep -e '^|' -e '||' -e '|$' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find null fields including the first and last field.

```
awk -F\| '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="") { print $0; next } }' file.csv > out.txt
```

Comment: This won't find lines where the last field is empty.

Comment: yes.. i see all the given lines having last field as empty.. that's why i put NF-1. @SinghChan has to clarify on this

Comment: It can ignore last field

Comment: Start with `i=0` and use `i<=NF` as the condition to catch first and last fields

Comment: Thanks for the help kamaraj ,one more thing is there any way ican specify which column have to be checked for null value , For example suppose user want to check column no. 1 , column no. 4 column no. 6 and column no 9

Comment: you can do like this...    awk -F\| ' $1=="" || $4=="" ' input.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with awk. It will print the line number of a match.

```
$ awk  '/^\|/ || /\|\|/ || /\|$/{print $0}' input_test 
apple|banana|pear||grapefruit
|tangerine|nectarine|plum
apricot|orange|pineapple|coconut|
```

Based on your revisions to the  original question I have reworked the awk command.

Explanation: 
Awk will match one of three conditions

- /\|\|/ will match any null field that is not the first or last field.
- /^\|/ will match any null field at the start of a line- the "^".
- /\|$/ will match any null field at the  end of a line- the "$".

Since awk recognizes | as an operator, when we try to match an "|" we need to use a "\" in front of it.

Now, these 3 conditions are strung together with a "||" which awk interprets as "or." Then when one of those 3 conditions is matched, the whole line will be printed.

To match a specific column(s) as null you can use

```
awk -F"|" '!length($1) || !length($4) {print $0} ' input_test
```

Comment: this wont catch the lines having the first field as empty

Comment: $ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2015 Free Software Foundation.
and I tested with ||hyrhyf|123|ma|fhyr|@#$%|

Comment: you should test with |hyrhyf|123|test|fhyr|@#$%|

Comment: because, in your example, first and second field is empty. so your awk command is working.

Comment: @Kamarj you were correct so I corrected my response

Comment: I didnt get you , above awk command will work on all the column or only for the first and second one

Comment: HI @rcjohnson Thanks for your help , is there any possibilities that i can iterate on number of column (max of 50 column)and check whether it contain null value or not , also column no. are random  like col1, col4, col6 ,col11

Comment: @SinghChan The description of what you are asking for is not very clear to me. It seems that if you want to step through each of the fields and test them individually, the results will be the same as if you tested for ANY null field. If you have a RANDOM set of null fields then, then iterating through them would still return the same results as testing for ANY null. If you can provide a description of what your ultimate goal is, we may be better able to advise you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0):

```
$ cat pipe.dat
apple|banana||pear||grapefruit
lemon|lime|damson|jackfruit
|tangerine|nectarine|plum
apricot|orange|pineapple|coconut|

$ cat has-blanks.mlr
@has_empty = false;
for (k,v in $*) {
    if (v == "") {
        @has_empty = true;
        break;
    }
}
filter @has_empty;

$ cat pipe.dat | mlr --nidx --fs pipe put -f has-blanks.mlr
apple|banana||pear||grapefruit
|tangerine|nectarine|plum
apricot|orange|pineapple|coconut|
```